# PHPUnit how to mock newly created model

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

How I'm stuck with writing a test for the following code. I want to mock the $userModel but how can I add this to the test?

```
class PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExist extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    public function isValid($email, $context = NULL)
    {
        $userModel = new Application_Model_User();
        $user = $userModel->findByEmailReseller($email, $context['reseller']);

        if ($user == NULL) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: the Solution**

I did change my class to the following to get it testable, it now uses dependency injection. More information about dependency injection you van find out [here](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection)

I now call the class like this:

```
new PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExist(new Application_Model_User()
```

The refactored class

```
class PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExist extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    protected $_userModel;

    public function  __construct($model)
    {
        $this->_userModel = $model;
    }

    public function isValid($email, $context = NULL)
    {
        if ($this->_userModel->findByEmailReseller($email, $context['reseller']) == NULL) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test

```
class PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExistTest extends BaseControllerTestCase
{
    protected $_userModelMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->_userModelMock = $this->getMock('Application_Model_User', array('findByEmailReseller'));
    }

    public function testIsValid()
    {
        $this->_userModelMock->expects($this->once())
                        ->method('findByEmailReseller')
                        ->will($this->returnValue(NULL));

        $validate = new PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExist($this->_userModelMock);
        $this->assertTrue(
                $validate->isValid('jef@test.com', NULL),
                'The email shouldn\'t exist'
        );
    }

    public function testIsNotValid()
    {
        $userStub = new \Entities\User();

        $this->_userModelMock->expects($this->once())
                        ->method('findByEmailReseller')
                        ->will($this->returnValue($userStub));

        $validate = new PC_Validate_UserEmailDoesNotExist($this->_userModelMock);
        $this->assertFalse(
                $validate->isValid('jef@test.com', NULL),
                'The email should exist'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you cant, because you hardcoded the dependency into the method.

There is three workarounds for this:

1) Make the used classname configurable, so you can do something like:

```
$className = $this->userModelClassName;
$userModel = new $className();
```

or 2) Add a third param to the method signature that allows passing in the dependency

```
public function isValid($email, $context = NULL, $userModel = NULL)
{
    if($userModel === NULL)
    {
        $userModel = new Application_Model_User();
    }
    // ...
}
```

or 3) use `set_new_overload()` as described in

- http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html
- http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers

> **Note:** [the Test-Helper extension is superseded](https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/457816903881588736) by https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz

Comment: Thanks!
How should this class be written when we had created the test first?

Comment: @Skelton In any way that does not hardcode the dependency. That would be something along the lines of Option 1 or 2 then

Comment: Thx! I did added the complete solution to my post.